# How do I prevent Tableau's auto-conversion of date formats?

Tags: date, file-io, tableau-api

I'm trying to build a Tableau dashboard with two [statistical files](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_statfile.htm) as input (these files have been generated as output of r code).

I need to join these two files together. The join condition includes date inequality conditions of the form

```
[Row Date] >= [Start Date]
[Row Date] <= [End Date]
```

In the raw data the dates are all in the "yyyy-mm-dd" format, but Tableau is converting all values to a format similar to "dd/mm/yy" except that the "dd" component is sometimes "d".

This is causing my join to fail, so I'd like to prevent this auto conversion. If this is not possible I would accept an approach of creating new fields based off of these date fields which have the correct format and then doing the join based on those newly created fields, but this is not ideal since it would add overhead to an already expensive join.

So how can I prevent Tableau's auto conversion of dates?

Answer (score 0):

You can force Tableau to interpret the raw fields as strings rather than as dates (just right click the variable in the Tableau data pane and use the `Change Data Type` menu). Then you can write an explicit string manipulation function to coerce the format into a standard one Tableau will interpret correctly.

After that, joining or blending the two tables will be easier. You can also do this when opening the data source while looking at the tabular view of the data.

Of course, the best solution is the make sure the script that creates the data puts dates into a standard ISO compatible date format.

Comment: Wait, isn't YYYY-MM-DD a [standard ISO compatible date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)? Also, this option doesn't appear in the tabular view of the data on the Data Source tab, only on the data pane of a sheet. I'm concerned that converting to string then back to date adds overhead every time I update the data and the join is executed - is there any way to *prevent* the conversion from happening in the first place?